# Bounce Effect not working. Background image causing it to not work?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to create a simple jQuery bounce effect for when the page loads, though later on I will add a delay, but regardless, right now the bounce effect doesn't even work.

Is this possible with a background image? If so, what am I doing wrong?

```js
$(window).load(function() {
  $("#circle-arrow").effect("bounce", {
    times: 4,
    distance: 200
  }, 400);
});
```

```css
#blue {
  background: blue;
  height: 400px;
  width: 100%;
}
#home-arrow {
 width: 100%;
 position: absolute;
 top: 25%;
 z-index: 999;
}
#circle-arrow {
  background-image: url("http://optimumwebdesigns.com/images/circle-arrow.png");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  margin: auto auto;
  position: relative;
  top: 60%;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<div id="blue">
  <div id="home-arrow">
    <div id="circle-arrow"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `$(document).ready();` instead of `$(window).load();`

https://jsfiddle.net/4b9m0wxh/

Comment: I think my issue may have been how I was trying to load the jquery ui. How did you upload it?

Comment: Also it seems the bounce goes downward instead of upwards. Anyway to change that? What I mean is if you look at it, it goes down and then bounces and then when the bounce is done, it goes back up to its static point.

Comment: Hmm maybe try solution with css3 - much cleaner and faster then jquery-ui. https://jsfiddle.net/gg12zh7v/

Comment: That is definitely much better. I tweaked it some. I just can't figure out how to add a delay to it. It appears the normal delay function won't work, so I'm trying to figure out a setTimeout approach.

Comment: Nevermind... I got it, I just had to take the class bounce out of the html. Thanks!Q

Answer (score 1):

Why not use CSS3 animations instead of jQuery UI Bounce effect? It's much cleaner and will provide much higher performance (especially on touch devices).

Check this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/zsj9ycwu/

You can change the delay (specified in ms) to suit your needs.

JS

```
var delay = 1000, circle = $('#circle-arrow'); 

$(document).ready(function(){
    circle.addClass('bounce-in');
    setTimeout(function(){ circle.removeClass('bounce-in'); },delay);
});
```

CSS

```
#circle-arrow {
  -webkit-transition: all 600ms cubic-bezier(0.68, -0.55, 0.265, 1.55);
  transition:         all 600ms cubic-bezier(0.68, -0.55, 0.265, 1.55);
  transform: scale(0,0);
  -webkit-transform: scale(0,0);
  opacity:0;
}
#circle-arrow.bounce-in{
  transform: scale(1,1);
  -webkit-transform: scale(1,1);
  opacity:1;
}
```

Comment: I'm all for cleaner and better working via mobile, but the jsfiddle you uploaded is nowhere near what I would want. It doesn't even bounce and it goes away after loading?

Comment: How about this instead, then? https://jsfiddle.net/zsj9ycwu/1/ The code before was a basic example of how it'd be done better, not a complete production-ready piece of code (I assumed you'd be okay swapping out the simple scale animation I used for something more complex). Animation keyframes taken from Animate.css https://daneden.github.io/animate.css/